# is there a way to eval() export in js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

i want to generate code that creates actions and actions creators for redux
when i tried to do that the app breaks and tells me that i cannot eval export
is there a way to do this?
example of the code:

```
const actions = ['GET_USERS', 'GET_USERS_SUCCESS'];
let actions_to_evalute = '';

function createActions(actions) {
    actions.forEach(a => {
        actions_to_evalute += `const ${a} = '${a}';\n`;
        // create from action action creators
        let arr =  a.toLowerCase().split('_');
        console.log(arr)
        let maxIndex = arr.length-1;
        arr.forEach((val, i)=>{
        console.log(val,i);
            if (i===0) {
                actions_to_evalute += `export function ${val}`;
            } else if (i>0 && i < maxIndex ) {
                actions_to_evalute += `${val.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${val.substring(1)}`
            } else if (i=== maxIndex) {
                actions_to_evalute += `${val.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${val.substring(1)}(){
                    return {
                        type: ${a}
                    }
                }\n`;
            }
        })
    });

    return actions_to_evalute;
}

eval(createActions(actions));
```

Comment: The problem is not with evaling the code. The problem is the export names `getUsers` and `getUserSuccess` cannot be variable. ES6 exports were designed to ban this behavior on purpose. Either doing it via eval or some other means such as default exporting an object ES6 spec does not allow having the export name being generated

Comment: There is a higher-level way around this though. Do what frameworks like React.js does: write script to output `.js` **files** and then import those files. Basically, write a proper file-to-file javascript compiler

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest to use `eval` in this case. One immediate drawback would be that code completion won't evaluate the output of it, so development is more cumbersome. Apart from that you always have to be careful when using it, to prevent syntax errors and security vulnerabilities.

One option would be to call `makeAction` once per action:

```js
function makeAction(name) {
  return () => {
    return {
      type: name
    }
  }
}

export const getUsers = makeAction('GET_USERS')
export const getUsersSuccess = makeAction('GET_USERS_SUCCESS')
```